# AWS cloud9 cannot create a new ssh environment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to create an ssh environment for a newly created ec2 instance, but the installer fails every time.

Steps:
Lanch a new ec2 instance, install node.js, add c9 ssh key, create new c9 ssh environment.

It seems like it installs another version of nodejs, and fails while creating a folder. It should be a routine operation, but I have no idea how to make it work.

Output log:

```
Installation Started

Package Cloud9 IDE 1
--------------------

Installing Node.js
+ SOURCE=-1
+ TARGET=/home/ubuntu/.c9/node
+ URL=http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
+ DIR=node-v6.3.1-linux-x64
+ '[' '!' -1 ']'
+ '[' '!' http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz ']'
+ '[' '!' /home/ubuntu/.c9/node ']'
+ '[' node-v6.3.1-linux-x64 ']'
+ set +e
+ rm -Rf /home/ubuntu/.c9/node
+ set -e
+ mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/.c9/node
+ cd /home/ubuntu/.c9/node
+ '[' http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz ']'
+ has wget
+ type wget
+ return 0
+ DOWNLOAD='wget --no-check-certificate -nc'
+ echo 'Downloading... http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz'
+ printf '\e[01;30m'
+ wget --no-check-certificate -nc http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
Downloading... http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
--2018-08-31 15:24:12--  http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving nodejs.org (nodejs.org)... 104.20.23.46, 104.20.22.46, 2400:cb00:2048:1::6814:162e, ...
Connecting to nodejs.org (nodejs.org)|104.20.23.46|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 13570047 (13M) [application/gzip]
Saving to: ‘node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  440K 30s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  859K 23s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1% 10.8M 15s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1% 10.3M 12s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1%  978K 12s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  2% 41.4M 10s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  2% 26.6M 9s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  3% 41.6M 8s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  3%  149K 16s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  3%  104M 15s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4% 66.6M 13s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4% 93.8M 12s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4% 46.4M 11s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  5% 92.1M 10s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  5% 82.4M 10s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  6% 63.1M 9s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  6% 78.8M 8s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  6% 14.9M 8s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  7% 81.6M 8s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  7% 70.0M 7s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  7% 65.1M 7s
  1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  8% 67.7M 6s
  1100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  8% 75.1M 6s
  1150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9% 40.6M 6s
  1200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9%  209M 6s
  1250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9% 35.2M 5s
  1300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 10%  220M 5s
  1350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 10%  212M 5s
  1400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 10% 27.9M 5s
  1450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11%  251M 5s
  1500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11%  228M 4s
  1550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12%  204M 4s
  1600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 26.1M 4s
  1650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12%  168M 4s
  1700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13%  193M 4s
  1750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13%  193M 4s
  1800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13%  122M 4s
  1850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 14% 78.6M 4s
  1900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 14% 35.3M 3s
  1950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 15%  176M 3s
  2000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 15%  229M 3s
  2050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 15% 79.4M 3s
  2100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16% 3.71M 3s
  2150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16%  101M 3s
  2200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16%  187M 3s
  2250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 17%  140M 3s
  2300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 17%  225M 3s
  2350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 18% 17.9M 3s
  2400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 18%  448M 3s
  2450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 18%  451M 3s
  2500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 19%  384M 3s
  2550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 19%  462M 3s
  2600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 19%  232M 2s
  2650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 20%  453M 2s
  2700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 20%  404M 2s
  2750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 21%  386M 2s
  2800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 21%  238M 2s
  2850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 21%  435M 2s
  2900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 22%  404M 2s
  2950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 22%  454M 2s
  3000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23%  394M 2s
  3050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23%  233M 2s
  3100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23%  358M 2s
  3150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 24%  456M 2s
  3200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 24%  459M 2s
  3250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 24%  462M 2s
  3300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 25% 20.7M 2s
  3350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 25% 82.0M 2s
  3400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 73.2M 2s
  3450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 67.8M 2s
  3500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 65.7M 2s
  3550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 27% 76.1M 2s
  3600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 27% 4.07M 2s
  3650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 27%  106M 2s
  3700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 28%  207M 2s
  3750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 28%  133M 2s
  3800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29%  160M 2s
  3850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29%  107M 2s
  3900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29%  197M 1s
  3950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 30%  237M 1s
  4000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 30%  175M 1s
  4050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 30%  249M 1s
  4100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 31%  127M 1s
  4150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 31%  113M 1s
  4200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32%  219M 1s
  4250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32%  283M 1s
  4300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32% 31.1M 1s
  4350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 33%  121M 1s
  4400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 33%  275M 1s
  4450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 33%  291M 1s
  4500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 34%  391M 1s
  4550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 34% 46.7M 1s
  4600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35% 85.6M 1s
  4650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35%  254M 1s
  4700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35%  318M 1s
  4750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 36%  241M 1s
  4800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 36%  203M 1s
  4850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 36% 26.7M 1s
  4900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 37%  205M 1s
  4950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 37%  223M 1s
  5000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 38%  195M 1s
  5050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 38%  192M 1s
  5100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 38% 24.6M 1s
  5150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  224M 1s
  5200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  224M 1s
  5250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  180M 1s
  5300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 40%  227M 1s
  5350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 40% 17.8M 1s
  5400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41%  211M 1s
  5450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41%  186M 1s
  5500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41%  215M 1s
  5550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42%  222M 1s
  5600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42% 28.0M 1s
  5650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43%  187M 1s
  5700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43%  216M 1s
  5750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43%  213M 1s
  5800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 44%  209M 1s
  5850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 44% 17.2M 1s
  5900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 44%  232M 1s
  5950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45%  229M 1s
  6000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45%  234M 1s
  6050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 46% 9.28M 1s
  6100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 46%  179M 1s
  6150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 46%  201M 1s
  6200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 47%  192M 1s
  6250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 47%  191M 1s
  6300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 47%  118M 1s
  6350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 48%  215M 1s
  6400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 48%  206M 1s
  6450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  184M 1s
  6500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  216M 1s
  6550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49% 11.8M 1s
  6600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 50%  228M 1s
  6650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 50%  198M 1s
  6700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 50%  214M 1s
  6750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 51%  207M 1s
  6800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 51% 14.0M 1s
  6850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52%  187M 1s
  6900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52%  206M 1s
  6950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52%  204M 1s
  7000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 53%  240M 1s
  7050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 53% 96.1M 1s
  7100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 53%  216M 1s
  7150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 54%  197M 1s
  7200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 54%  229M 1s
  7250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 55%  107M 1s
  7300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 55%  219M 1s
  7350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 55%  244M 1s
  7400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 56%  201M 1s
  7450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 56%  175M 1s
  7500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 56% 28.0M 1s
  7550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57%  207M 1s
  7600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57%  231M 0s
  7650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 58%  172M 0s
  7700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 58%  234M 0s
  7750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 58% 33.8M 0s
  7800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59% 48.1M 0s
  7850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59%  181M 0s
  7900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59%  196M 0s
  7950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 60%  216M 0s
  8000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 60%  104M 0s
  8050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 61% 26.1M 0s
  8100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 61%  218M 0s
  8150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 61%  188M 0s
  8200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 62%  204M 0s
  8250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 62%  194M 0s
  8300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 63% 22.1M 0s
  8350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 63%  228M 0s
  8400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 63%  254M 0s
  8450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 64%  202M 0s
  8500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 64%  199M 0s
  8550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 64% 28.2M 0s
  8600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 65% 77.5M 0s
  8650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 65%  186M 0s
  8700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66%  234M 0s
  8750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66%  188M 0s
  8800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66% 60.1M 0s
  8850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 67% 32.9M 0s
  8900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 67%  215M 0s
  8950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 67%  232M 0s
  9000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 68%  219M 0s
  9050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 68%  182M 0s
  9100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69% 25.1M 0s
  9150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69%  372M 0s
  9200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69%  353M 0s
  9250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 70%  338M 0s
  9300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 70%  378M 0s
  9350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 70% 60.8M 0s
  9400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 71% 88.6M 0s
  9450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 71%  335M 0s
  9500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 72%  394M 0s
  9550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 72%  409M 0s
  9600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 72%  391M 0s
  9650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73% 38.7M 0s
  9700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73%  405M 0s
  9750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73%  394M 0s
  9800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 74%  394M 0s
  9850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 74% 2.99M 0s
  9900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 75% 51.7M 0s
  9950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 75%  152M 0s
 10000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 75% 61.6M 0s
 10050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 76%  218M 0s
 10100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 76% 49.7M 0s
 10150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 76%  145M 0s
 10200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 77% 55.3M 0s
 10250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 77% 63.2M 0s
 10300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 78%  154M 0s
 10350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 78% 50.8M 0s
 10400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 78%  210M 0s
 10450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79% 60.4M 0s
 10500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79% 90.3M 0s
 10550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79%  218M 0s
 10600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 80% 41.0M 0s
 10650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 80%  195M 0s
 10700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 81%  150M 0s
 10750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 81% 41.6M 0s
 10800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 81%  213M 0s
 10850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 82%  135M 0s
 10900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 82% 38.8M 0s
 10950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 83%  233M 0s
 11000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 83%  244M 0s
 11050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 83% 34.8M 0s
 11100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 84%  222M 0s
 11150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 84%  241M 0s
 11200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 84% 86.8M 0s
 11250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 85% 84.0M 0s
 11300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 85% 84.9M 0s
 11350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 86% 86.3M 0s
 11400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 86%  195K 0s
 11450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 86%  253M 0s
 11500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 87%  410M 0s
 11550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 87%  329M 0s
 11600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 87%  431M 0s
 11650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 88% 17.5M 0s
 11700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 88%  384M 0s
 11750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 89%  310M 0s
 11800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 89%  343M 0s
 11850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 89%  342M 0s
 11900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90%  132M 0s
 11950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90%  278M 0s
 12000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90%  401M 0s
 12050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 91%  364M 0s
 12100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 91%  379M 0s
 12150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 92%  121M 0s
 12200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 92%  345M 0s
 12250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 92%  355M 0s
 12300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 93%  311M 0s
 12350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 93%  136M 0s
 12400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 93%  351M 0s
 12450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 94%  128M 0s
 12500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 94%  371M 0s
 12550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 95%  323M 0s
 12600K .......... .......... Unpacking... /home/ubuntu/.c9/node/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
Merging... /home/ubuntu/.c9/node/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64 in /home/ubuntu/.c9/node

.......... .......... .......... 95%  127M 0s
 12650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 95%  379M 0s
 12700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 96%  380M 0s
 12750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 96%  314M 0s
 12800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 96%  344M 0s
 12850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 97%  104M 0s
 12900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 97%  356M 0s
 12950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98%  175M 0s
 13000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98%  272M 0s
 13050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98%  377M 0s
 13100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%  345M 0s
 13150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%  339M 0s
 13200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%  198M 0s
 13250K .                                                     100% 3813G=1.0s

2018-08-31 15:24:13 (12.9 MB/s) - ‘node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz’ saved [13570047/13570047]

+ printf '\e[0m'
++ basename http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
+ SOURCE=/home/ubuntu/.c9/node/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
++ dirname /home/ubuntu/.c9/node/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
++ dirname /home/ubuntu/.c9/node/x
+ '[' /home/ubuntu/.c9/node '!=' /home/ubuntu/.c9/node ']'
+ echo 'Unpacking... /home/ubuntu/.c9/node/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz'
+ printf '\e[01;30m'
+ tar -U -zxf /home/ubuntu/.c9/node/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
+ printf '\e[0m'
+ rm -Rf /home/ubuntu/.c9/node/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
+ '[' node-v6.3.1-linux-x64 ']'
+ echo 'Merging... /home/ubuntu/.c9/node/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64 in /home/ubuntu/.c9/node'
+ printf '\e[01;30m'
+ merge
+ mkdir -p c9_tmp
+ rm -rf c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64
+ mv node-v6.3.1-linux-x64 c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64
+ mv c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/bin c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/CHANGELOG.md c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/include c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/lib c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/LICENSE c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/README.md c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/share .
+ set +e
+ mv c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/. c9_tmp/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/.. .
+ set -e
+ rm -rf c9_tmp
+ printf '\e[0m'
+ echo 
+ sleep 2
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1065-aws
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.c9/node/bin/npm" "config" "-g" "set" "cache" "/home/ubuntu/.c9/tmp/.npm"
npm ERR! node v8.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /usr/etc
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/etc'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/etc' errno: -13, code: 'EACCES', syscall: 'mkdir', path: '/usr/etc' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.c9/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1065-aws
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.c9/node/bin/npm" "config" "-g" "set" "python" "python2.7"
npm ERR! node v8.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /usr/etc
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/etc'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/etc' errno: -13, code: 'EACCES', syscall: 'mkdir', path: '/usr/etc' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.c9/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1065-aws
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.c9/node/bin/npm" "config" "-g" "set" "unsafe-perm" "true"
npm ERR! node v8.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /usr/etc
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/etc'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/etc' errno: -13, code: 'EACCES', syscall: 'mkdir', path: '/usr/etc' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.c9/npm-debug.log

Failed Bash. Exit code E_MISSING_END_MARKER

One or more errors occured. Please try to resolve them and restart AWS Cloud9 or visit https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=268
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve that problem by **giving a root privilege to the user**.

This will help you:
https://www.shellhacks.com/how-to-grant-root-access-user-root-privileges-linux/